Inserting a .eps graphic leads to a black square roughly the size of that graphic, how can this be avoided?
I'm currently trying to write my master thesis in chemistry, using chemnum to number my compounds and therefore using .eps files for my structures, schemes and other things.
However, when I try to introduce them with includegraphics, I always get a black square roughly the size of the image at the bottom left of my screen.
I have included a minimum working example, that, at least on my TexMaker distribution with MikTex leads to the issues as I have described.
I compile using the Quick Build (LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf + View PDF) with the commands for LaTeX being "latex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex -shell-escape"
I hope anyone can help me, because I myself can't figure it out, and I also hope I typed everything out correctly.
Best wishes
Paul
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,bibliography=totocnumbered,listof=totocnumbered, onehalfspacing]{scrartcl}

%Packages dealing with Fonts / Texts
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

%Packages dealing with Mathematics
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%Packages dealing with Images / Graphics
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[crop=off, runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\graphicspath{{./Bilder/}}

%Packages dealing with Tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

%Packages dealing with colouration
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}

%Packages dealing with the geometry / order 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage[automark,autooneside=false,headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

%Packages dealing with Text Orientation
\usepackage{paralist}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

%Packages dealing with Citation
%\usepackage[superscript,ref]{cite}
\usepackage[super, comma, numbers, square, sort]{natbib}

%Packages dealing with numeration of Molecules / Reactions
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage[modules={schemes,chemgreek}]{chemmacros}



%Additional Packages
%\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \replacecmpd[tag=PG01]{Benzene}
    \includegraphics[]{MWE.eps}
    \caption{Structure of Benzene (\refcmpd{Benzene})}
    \label{BenzeneStruk}
\end{figure}

Shown in figure \ref{BenzeneStruk} is the molecular structure of Benzene (\cmpd{Benzene}).

\end{document}

If necessary, I can include both the image (a benzene molecule with a tag for the chemnum below) and the pdf it produces for me or share those through a file transfer service.

Update:
I have added a link for the MWE.eps file and a PDF of how it looks on my end
I have also shrunken the code down, thinking that if I kept all the packages loaded that I normally use it could be necessary for the error, and, as has been pointed out in the comments, other errors that I make are also apparent.
I have also cleared all the files apart from the .tex and eps file and rerun the code using the above mentioned compilation.
The minimal code that shows the same error I have been encountering is this:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{MWE.eps}
Shown is the molecular structure of Benzene.
\end{document}

I am sorry for including way to much information.
Paul

You need to fix your package use, you say you are using latex/dvips (why not pdflatex?)  but you have \usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx}  which will not work, delete the [dvipdfm] option, similarly \usepackage[crop=off, runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf} is for pdftex so will not work wth latex/dvips, use pstricks. (but your document is not using pstricks so you can simply delete this, and most of the other packages from this example)

@cabohah Thanks, removed

Sorry, but without your MWE.eps we are not able to reproduce the issue. Does is also happen, if you remove all not used packages from the document preamble? Does is also happen, if you comment \replacecmpd[…]{…}? Does is also happen, if you replace MWE.eps by another eps, e.g., a copy of example-image.eps from package mwe?

I've tried with scheme-tmp.ps from chemnum package instead of MWE.eps and also replaced \replacecmpd[tag=PG01]{Benzene} by \replacecmpd[tag=TMP1]{Benzene} but still cannot reproduce the issue.

See also the comments to your previous question (about the same mistakes there, e.g., wrong driver option, usage of auto-pst-pdf …).

@DavidCarlisle I use LaTeX/dvips because for some reason, compiling with PDFLaTeX just didn't work / crashed and I didn't understand the log for why it crashed. On the other hand, the quickbuild compiler I did use seemed to work, so that's what I did (with little understanding of why, despite using LaTeX since my Bachelors).

still if you want help with any problem on this site you need to show code that is related to the problem, you are asking people to trace tex's behaviour, do you only get the black square if \usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} is used? if not why is it in the example? similarly any other package.  I suspect almost every line of code shown is unrelated to your question, and the parts that are related are using an image not provided. (you could use example-image-a.eps and then replace A by something.) Assuming you need the psfrag replacement to show your problem, although that is not clear.

@cabohah I have uploaded the eps file. It happens with other eps files I have created, I will get on with the other example you provided. I have also just now gotten home and reproduced it on my home computer. I have to be honest, when the document finally worked and didn't output any errors the last time, I forgot to fix those issues and just continued on, thinking "what isn't really broken doesn't need fixing." I'll get on that now, and see if these mistakes are the cause, and disable packages that shouldn't be needed.

I don't think you can use pdfpages unless you're using pdfTeX (or something else which produces pdf) since the engine you're using can't use pdf images, which is the whole point. so either you don't need the package or you need a different compiler.

@cfr I was originally using PdfLaTeX to compile, for some reason that didn't work anymore. Switching to LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf + View Pdf seemed to fix that error. That is until I encountered the other error with black frame. I have now switched back to PdfLaTeX + View PDF and it compiles fine. I am unsure if that means I should remove pdfpages and the [dvipdf] option, as I am sure I had a reason for including them. At some point.

so comment them out and test. but my point wasn't whether you need it or not but whether you could need it with latex rather than an engine which produces pdf. you can't use dvipdfm and pdfpages or auto-pst-pdf because the first is only useful if you're producing dvi and the second and third only useful if you're producing pdf. packages and options you don't need are just a source of potential problems. this isn't a case of the more the better. the code you load doesn't just add features. it changes/modifies features and increases the potential for conflicts.

@cfr thank you for the comment and explanation. I did cut down as much as possible to still reproduce the error. But since it now works fully as intended using PdfLaTeX, I am not sure I actually still need to solve this issue. I figured out why PdfLaTeX did not work, there was something wrong with the parameters.

The eps file is defective. I don't know what caused this, but the following fixed it for me.
1 - Open the eps file with your favourite text editor.
2 - On the first line, delete everything that comes before
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-1.2

All of this is trash.
3 - Create a new line after line 446, and on it, insert
[1 0 0 1 -880 -2233] concat

So, where you did have
newpath
4978 5692.5 moveto

you now have
newpath
[1 0 0 1 -880 -2233] concat
4978 5692.5 moveto

4 - Save the file.
The issue seems to be that all paths are shifted up and right except one, and this draws a black rectangle below and to the left of the actual figure. Adding the extra line as above moves this to where it's presumably supposed to be (deleting the offending path entirely also seems to work).

This is kind of interesting and weird, because when I remove all packages and compile with PdfLaTeX, I do not get the black square. I also do not understand what would cause this eps file to be defective. I have done a clean install of chemdraw on both of my devices and simply exported my structures as eps files. There shouldn't be a reason for chemdraw to break them. And as I said, when compiling with PdfLaTeX, they do work as intended.
(Link to a file upload: https://we.tl/t-6O6lttkZjU )

Items outside the eps bounding box (as in this case) will cause unpredictable effects. Some viewers won't display them at all, and some processes (such as converting to pdf) may automatically crop them. It seems that inclusion via dvips does display them. I've never used chemdraw, but my guess is that this is a bug.
